# Как получить relations у модели, без явного вызова Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel

Проблема такая.
Есть Eloquent Model пользователя.
В ней есть связи wishlist, access_token, friends и т.д.

Встал вопрос миграции аккаунтов. 
Так вот вопрос как получить все relations у модели? Не вызывая явным образом метода подгрузки?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что отношения загружаются в свойство `$relations` модели в момент оперирования записями. Например, при "[жадной](http://laravel.su/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading)" загрузке этих самых отношений с помощью метода `with` во время выборки данных или при сохранении данных со связыванием и т.п.

До этого момента отношения еще не сохранены в свойстве `$relations` у модели, поскольку ни разу не были затронуты.

Если же запись выбрана и получен инстанс модели, то можно получить загруженные отношения с помощью публичного метода модели [`getRelations()`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getRelations) или метода [`relationsToArray()`](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_relationsToArray).

Иными словами, если под подгрузкой вы понимаете процесс выборки данных из базы, то задача нерешаема на основе ваших данных.

---

Если бы все связи имели какой-то паттерн в имени, (например, метод `getWishlist()`, где `Wishlist` имя связываемой модели), то вы могли бы получить все методы класса с помощью [`ReflectionClass::getMethods`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reflectionclass.getmethods.php) и отфильтровать нужные, проверяя потенциальные имена моделей с помощью [`instanceof`](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.type.php).

Должен предупредить, что идея так себе.

---

Самое простое решение: создать защищенное статичное свойство в модели, где вы будете хранить информацию о связях в нужном вам виде.

Только так вы будете иметь доступ к связям без загрузки данных.

Использована информация отсюда: [Get all relationships from Eloquent model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334843/get-all-relationships-from-eloquent-model)